# Need Script to Accept Cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am making a spreadsheet on google sheets, and I need this script to accept a cell. For example, I want to do "=getPrice(A1)" but it will not work. It will only work if you do "=getPrice(2)" with 2 being any number that is in the api.

```
function getPrice(id)
{
  Utilities.sleep(5000);
  try
  {

    var api = "http://services.runescape.com/m=itemdb_rs/api/graph/";
    var i = JSON.parse(UrlFetchApp.fetch(api + id + ".json"))["daily"];
    var e = Object.keys(i).sort().reverse()[0];
    return i[e];
  }
  catch(err)
  {
    return -1;
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `INDIRECT`?

Comment: The approach `=getPrice(A1)` should work. Note that this is different than `=getPrice("A1")`, which passes the string `"A1"` instead of the value of the cell A1.  Consider debugging your script by logging the arguments it receives, e.g. `console.log(id);` and then *View -> Stackdriver Logs*

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who has this problem, use indirect in the cell.

=Getprice(Indirect("C"&"4"))

Thanks to Ron Kloberdanz

Comment: How were you using it before? `=getPrice(C4)` or `=getPrice("C4")`? If you just type the `=getPrice(` portion and click the cell, then finish with the closing `)`, you should be ok